# What Dos interupt do i need to use to output time and date?

Tags: windows, assembly, time, dos, tasm

I am using int 21-2AH and 2CH to get the time and date and understand what registers the results are returned. But when i use int 21-2 to output it i just get a funny character. What do i use to output to screen correctly? I am using Tasm

Answer (score 1):

2Ch returns the hours/minutes/seconds/centi-seconds as binary numbers. You can't output them directly, as you'll get just whatever character is that spot in the ASCII table. You'll have to conver those binary numbers into ascii strings first.